# elsif conditon not working in a rails block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method (self.invoice_magistrates) that invoices existing members that meet certain criteria ie. they are active members and have prior payments.

The problem is at the elsif line: (elsif !magistrate.payments.last.paid_this_month?) even when this is false it still creates the payment, .

I have a similar method (self.invoice_judges) that runs properly. Hope you can help me thank you.

```
     //checks whether payment was made in the current month
     def paid_this_month?
      self.date.strftime("%B %Y") ==  Date.today.strftime("%B %Y")
     end

    //problematic code
    def self.invoice_magistrates
      count = 0
      Member.magistrates.active.includes(:payments).each do |magistrate|
        if magistrate.payments.empty?
          deactivate_member(magistrate)
        //even when false it still creates payment
        elsif !magistrate.payments.last.paid_this_month?
          count += 1
          amount_to_pay = PaymentPlan.last.magistrate
          magistrate.payments.create(:invoice => amount_to_pay, :amount => amount_to_pay,    :balance => 0, :date => Time.now.to_date, :region => magistrate.region)
       end
     end
     return count
   end

    //similar method that runs correctly although the members are less
    def self.invoice_judges
      count = 0
      Member.judges.active.includes(:payments).each do |judge|
        if judge.payments.empty?
          deactivate_member(judge)
        elsif !judge.payments.last.paid_this_year?
          count += 1
          amount_to_pay = PaymentPlan.last.judge
          balance = judge.balance + amount_to_pay
          judge.payments.create!(:date => Time.now.beginning_of_year.to_date, :invoice => amount_to_pay, :amount => 0, :balance => balance, :region => judge.region)
          judge.update_column(:balance, balance)
       end
     end
     return count
   end
```

Comment: why do not you inspect and see whether control really enters into that  elsif condition; use rails logger or print statements.....

Comment: Yea it does enter in all of the false cases

Comment: Is the space in `| magistrate|` a typo in the question or in your code?

Comment: My bad that was a typo in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from `| magistrate|` ...

```
Member.magistrates.active.includes(:payments).each do |magistrate|
```

I would probably try to make the conditions more specific, however without an example set of data it's pretty much impossible to troubleshoot what is happening.

Also, reading `elsif !something?` is pretty non-intuitive. You'd be better off writing a new method on the model so you can do `elsif not_something?`

```
def self.invoice_magistrates
  count = 0
  Member.magistrates.active.includes(:payments).each do |magistrate|
    if magistrate.payments.empty?
      deactivate_member(magistrate)
    elsif magistrate.unpaid_this_month?
      count += 1
      amount_to_pay = PaymentPlan.last.magistrate
      magistrate.payments.create(:invoice => amount_to_pay, :amount => amount_to_pay,    :balance => 0, :date => Time.now.to_date, :region => magistrate.region)
    end
  end
  return count
end
```

If it's still making payments when you think it shouldn't, then either the data you're using isn't what you think it is, or this logic is incorrect: `!magistrate.payments.last.paid_this_month?`

Comment: My bad that was a typo in the question

Comment: For the elsif as you suggest I tried with a method that does not negate (self.date.strftime("%B %Y") !=  Date.today.strftime("%B %Y")) same result (problem with logic) as the negating one. The data is the same as that of the self.invoice_judges method and the logic too is the same. I don't suppose the size could be a problem as the collection Member.magistrates.active has around 4000 compared to 200 for Member.judges.active.

Comment: what the data looks like:                                             Members                                                                   #<Member id: 99, first_name: "name", designation: "judge", region: "region1", active: true, balance: 0>                                                                                                               Payments:                                                            #<Payment id: 1, member_id: 2, region: "region2", invoice: 0, amount: 0, total_amount: nil, balance: 0, date: "2014-01-25">

Comment: I think you'd probably benefit from abstracting this code away from your controller. How about calling something like `Member.make_pending_payments` in your controller and putting the logic for who and how much to pay in the model?

Comment: These are class methods in a model. The intention is to do batch invoicing for all members who meet criteria for membership. The invoices are similar for similar designations hence the batch invoicing. The methods are then called from a controller eg. Member.invoice_magistrates

Comment: In which case, the next sensible step would be to write some tests for your model and debug the failing tests.

Comment: Yea I really should have done TDD from the on-set. Running the same code in development with a small data set behaves ok. However, in production with a bigger data set it completely breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Member.magistrates.active.includes(:payments)
```

includes() does not guarantee any ordering so

```
magistrate.payments.last
```

does not always return the last payment.